# How to load Stata file (.dta) in SQL?

Tags: sql, stata

I am a Stata user and a new to SQL, so being able to read Stata files directly would be a big step. Please let me know if this is doable.

Comment: See `help odbc`

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `odbc` as Wouter suggested or go through Python. Then you can use the `pandas` library.